# Ada TASKING_ERROR

Tags: concurrency, task, ada

Assume the following situation:
There is a box, which is used to store coins
People take money from the box
People put money into the box
i have take task entry as  Add, Subtract, Read and Write. below is my code .now i am confused how to call entry add ,subtract and read to achieve above requirement   please help

```
with Ada.Text_IO,ada.integer_text_io;
use ada.text_io,ada.integer_text_io;

procedure protected_imp is
   task type box(initial_value:integer;min_value:integer;max_value:integer) is
      entry add(number:integer); 
      entry subtract(number:integer);
      entry read;
   end box;
   task body box is 
      x:integer:=initial_value; --shared variable
   begin
      loop                  --why raised TASKING_ERROR when loop is removed?
         select
            when x<max_value=>
               accept add(number:integer)do
                  x:=x+number;
               end add;
         or  
            when x>min_value=>
               accept subtract(number:integer) do
                  x:=x-number;
               end subtract;
         or
            accept read do
               put("coins");
               put_line(integer'image(x));
            end read;
         or
            delay(5.0);
            put("no request received for 5 seconds");
         end select;
      end loop;
   end box;
   go:box(1,0,10);
begin ----- how to call? and why  i am getting "no request received for 5 seconds " even i have activate go .add(1) ?
   for i in 1..5 loop
      go.add(1);
   end loop;
   go.read;
end protected_imp;
```

Comment: Thank you for providing compilable code! Any chance you could format it better?

Comment: @SimonWright sorry sir i coudln't get you i am new to ada and this stackover flow i tired my best based on my knowledge

Comment: Actually, I got the impression from your question’s edit history that you couldn’t just paste the code in from your computer; if that’s so, you have my sympathy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, your program produces the output

```
$ ./protected_imp 
coins 6
no request received for 5 secondsno request received for 5 secondsno request received for 5 seconds^C
```

(I stopped it at that point).

“coins 6” is exactly the output it should give; you’ve added 1 to the starting value (1) 5 times.

The reason you get `Tasking_Error` if you remove the loop is that then the task executes the `select` statement once; after it accepts the `go.add` call it exits the `select` and drops out of the bottom of the task, so that the next `go.add` call has nowhere to go because there is no task any more.

The sequence of events is

```
task arrives at select; all the alternatives are closed
main calls go.add (1)'
task accepts the entry, increments x, exits the select, and goes round the loop again to wait at the select
main calls go.add (1)
task accepts the entry, increments x, exits the select, and goes round the loop again to wait at the select
main calls go.add (1)
task accepts the entry, increments x, exits the select, and goes round the loop again to wait at the select
main calls go.add (1)
task accepts the entry, increments x, exits the select, and goes round the loop again to wait at the select
main calls go.add (1)
task accepts the entry, increments x, exits the select, and goes round the loop again to wait at the select
main calls go.read
task accepts the entry, prints out “coins 6”, and goes round the loop again to wait at the select
main finishes and waits until the task terminates, which it doesn’t, because
after 5 seconds, the select’s delay alternative opens, so the task takes it, prints the message (it should really use Put_Line) and goes round the loop again to wait at the select
after 5 seconds, the select’s delay alternative opens, so the task takes it, prints the message and goes round the loop again to wait at the select
...
```

Comment: thank you sir,i got it and sir how can i take user input say  go.add(user_input) from one terminal  and print on other  terminal by task body box   like pipe system call in linux ?

Comment: You need to ask this in a new question (to which I’m pretty sure I wouldn’t know the answer)